# Updating SCORM content for all courses in Moodle

Tags: moodle, scorm

We have several courses in Moodle that all use the same SCORM package.  We want to be able to update the content without needing to go into each course and upload a new version as it is time-consuming.  I am exploring a programmatic solution and I have tried to update the "mdl_scorm" table with the new package sha1hash, reference, and name, but the old package still launches.  I've modified the values in "mdl_scorm_scoes" to match the new package as well without any luck. Where is moodle pulling the SCORM package location if not in one of the "mdl_scorm" tables?

Answer (score 0):

The package is stored as a file, so will be in the site data directory not the database. Although a file name+location is stored as a hash in the database.

I'd recommend looking at function `scorm_update_instance` in `/mod/scorm/lib.php`

This function is called when editing a scorm activity. It also calls `scorm_parse` which extracts the package file.

Maybe pass the data to the `scorm_update_instance` function and let Moodle do its thing.

For the data, see `/mod/scorm/mod_form.php`

Comment: The way I was going about it is to upload the new SCORM as another activity, then replace the values of that old mdl_scorm for reference, sha1hash, and title with the new record values.  But it's still pulling the reference to the old SCORM.  I am letting Moodle do the parsing and renaming with the hash, I am just trying to get the values out of the new record and make the old course instance point at the new one.

Comment: Do you know what table is feeding the iframe view of the scorm location?  I can see how moodle is breaking apart the package and how it's storing based on the sha1hash.